# How can i add custom font to font-awesome?

Tags: font-awesome

Font-awesome is limited to one font or ?. Is there any option to add custom font to font-awesome.

If yes then, show me how to add that.

Comment: Font Awesome IS a font....are you trying to add additional icons to the font? Is that your goal?

Comment: Hi @user362483 - your question is unspecific since font-awesome is a font and if you miss another font you should use another font. Please precise your question to become more specific.

Answer (score 0):

FontAwesome is a collection of icon fonts. If you want a collection with different icons one easy way is to use IconMoon - http://icomoon.io/app/#/select and http://icomoon.io/#icon-font  . Their IconMoon app is brilliant and hooks into a world of different options.

If you want actual web fonts, then it's hard to beat [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/) or [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) if you want to use your own fonts